# Docusign go-live review failure

Tags: docusignapi

We have a service integration with docusign. The envelope is created, in Draft mode, with API key A. Key A is already live in production.

We have a custom script that applies a template to the already created envelope and populates some mail notifications (custom) using API key B. Key B is a non-live key.

Each invocation, omitting the call for retrieving the base URL, the custom script (Key B) makes four calls for a particular envelope:

1. Apply template : POST
2. Get recipients : GET
3. Update recipients : PUT
4. Delete recipients : DELETE

At the end of this operation the updated envelope would still be in Draft mode.

Now, we make around 7 - 8 invocations of the custom script, each time for a different envelope, which gives us around 28 API calls and then try a key review. But every time it fails.

We're pretty sure that we are not crossing the hourly API call limit. Key B is not used elsewhere as well. Also, there're no repetitive GET requests to the same envelope endpoint.

The calls are made using standard java libraries. No SDK.

Is the sequence of calls made not a valid one?
Is there something we're missing here? We're sure that the key being used in script and the key we're trying to promote are the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend emailing go-live@docusign.com as per https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-API-Go-Live-Process-FAQ

Comment: Also this should help you debug the failure https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live-steps#review-failed

Answer (score 0):

In general, specific questions about the DocuSign Go-Live process should go to go-live@docusign.com. There is more information about the process here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live